# Very simple python function

Tags: python

```
def myfun(x,y):
    z=x+y
    Print("my x is", x)
    Print("my y is", y)
    Print("my z is", z)

myfun(1,2)
myfun(3,4)
myfun(5,6)
myfun(x,y)
```

This is an idea of what I want to do.  The first the 3 calls of the function are predetermined, and in the 4th one, I want to promt for user input, is there anyway I can do this with 1 function(without changing the formatting) because the final format needs to be..

```
my x is 1
my y is 2
my z is 3
my x is 3
my y is 4
my z is 5
my x is 5
my y is 6
my z is 7
my x is (userinput)
my y is (userinput)
my z is ...
```

Anyone way I can do this correctly with one function?

Comment: The built-in function [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) may be useful to you. (or [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), for non 3.X versions)

Comment: Combining user input and program logic in the same function is generally frowned on. What you want is a control function that uses stock numbers, numbers from an input file, or numbers from the user somehow. This then calls your `myfun`. Remember to think about "how would I test this?" and "Can I do it automatically?".

Comment: You want for Python to think 3+4=5 and 5+6=7? I don't think I want to use your version of Python...

Answer (score 2):

```
def myfun(x=0, y=0):
   z = x + y
   Print("My x is", x)
   Print("My y is", y)
   Print("My z is", z)

myfun(1,2)
myfun(3,4)
myfun(5,6)
# here you can make a input for x and y and then you type cast the string in int
x = int(raw_input('Input x: '))
y = int(raw_input('Input y: '))
myfun(x,y)
```

If you use Python 3.x, take input() instead of raw_input()

```
x = int(input('Input x: '))
y = int(input('Input y: '))
myfun(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this with ordinary values as parameters, referencing a local variable never does anything extra. You can, however, accept *functions* which supply a value. Then instead of passing some integer, you pass a function which returns an integer, and instead of changing `myfun` to do I/O, you just pass a function which does the I/O.

```
myfun(lambda: 5, lambda: 6)
# I'm gonna assume Python 3
myfun(input, input)
```

You need to write the function a bit differently though, because you want the input to happen at a precise point in time. Something like this:

```
def myfun(x_fun, y_fun):
    print("my x is", end=" ")
    x = x_fun()
    print("my y is", end=" ")
    y = y_fun()
    z=x+y
    print("my z is", z)
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
#myfun(x,y)
myfun(input("What is value of x? "),input("What is value of y? "))
```